# what is the proper way to deploy zookeeper with HBase?

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am defining the architecture of my Hadoop cluster where I also want to include Hbase and therefore Zookeeper. However, I don't know where I have to install my Zookeeper nodes with respect to my hadoop nodes. Here are my two possibilities

First possibility: (zookeeper cluster outside my hadoop cluster)
[image]

Second possibility: (zookeeper cluster within my hadoop cluster)
[image]

Can you tell me, regarding these two possibilities, what is the proper way to deploy Zookeeper with HBase ?

I also have an additional question: are The journalNodes and JobHistory Server at the right place ?

I would be very thankful for any help, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Most Hadoop clusters run with ZooKeeper as part of the cluster -- the second layout that you suggest.  It should generally be okay to have the ZK nodes overlap with the journal nodes and such.  If you are going to be using ZK outside of HBase then you need to consider the this placement and the disks that will be used by ZK.  ZK performance can be dramatically affected by the underlying disk usage.

Also typically ZK will have 3 nodes.  The number should definitely be odd.  See the [ZK admin guide](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_designing) for more details.